# parsing failed because a } isnt put in?

Tags: lua

Setting up a fivem server and trying to get esx_policejobs to work after putting in custom job_grades. Have gotten an error and have been stuck for hours, I don't know if I'm missing something here or not?

Theres also a console line that says stack traceback to a different .lua file, so could that end up being the problem in there instead of the actual config file?

Have looked over and over the config and honestly cant find the problem

```
    recruit = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 1500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 80 },
    },

    private = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    private-first-class = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 }
    },

    sergeant = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    lieutenant = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    captain = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    inspector = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    deputy-chief = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    assistant-chief = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },

    chief-of-police = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },
}
```

Shouldnt be any config errors

Error in console:

````
Failed to load script config.lua.
Error loading script server/main.lua in resource esx_policejob: @esx_policejob/server/main.lua:5: attempt to index a nil value (global 'Config')
stack traceback:
        @esx_policejob/server/main.lua:5: in main chunk```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the dashes in the table key names. The manual does give a hint about the form of the [table constructor](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9):

> > A field of the form name = exp is equivalent to ["name"] = exp.

A [name](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1) must be:

> > Names (also called identifiers) in Lua can be any string of letters, digits, and underscores, not beginning with a digit and not being a reserved word. Identifiers are used to name variables, table fields, and labels.

This means you have to use the second form of the table constructor `["name"] = exp` for anything that isn't valid identifier.

```
['chief-of-police'] = {
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_PUMPSHOTGUN', components = { 2000, 6000, nil }, price = 70000 },
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
    { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
}
```

Comment: so basically I need to rename 'chief-of-police' to something along the lines of 'chiefofpolice' ?

Comment: you can remove the dashes, or you can use quotes and brackets (ex. `['chief-of-police']`), either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code "private" reserved word:

```
>>>>private = {
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_APPISTOL', components = { 0, 0, 1000, 4000, nil }, price = 10000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_ADVANCEDRIFLE', components = { 0, 6000, 1000, 4000, 8000, nil }, price = 50000 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_NIGHTSTICK', price = 0 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_STUNGUN', price = 500 },
        { weapon = 'WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT', price = 0 },
    },
```

1. table must be constructed

```
    myTable = {}
```

2. after table exists, you can define key:

```
    myTable["some.key"] = {}
```

3. if you nead sub-key, next step will be:

```
    myTable["some.key"]["sub.key"] = {}  
    myTable["some.key"]["sub.key"]["value_1"] = "123"
    myTable["some.key"]["sub.key"]["value_2"] = "456"
```

at the end, you can use trick:

```
    local myTables = {}
    myTables["table_name"] = myTable
```

Comment: "private" is *not* a reserved word in Lua.